# Arrays and newtype pattern

Tags: rust, newtype

I have a type, that can be represented as f32, without NaN or infinity or negative values and with a maximum value, a trivial example could be people heights in meters, so I'm using the new type pattern to represent it:

```rust
struct Height(f32);

impl TryFrom<f32> for Height {
    type Error = &'static str;

    fn try_from(value: f32) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        if value.is_infinite() || value.is_sign_negative() || value > 3. {
            return Err("value was infinite");
        }
        Ok(Height(value))
    }
}
```

What I don't like is when I have to deal with an array of these, because it should be declared like

```rust
let vec = vec![Height::try_from(3.).unwrap(), Height::try_from(2.).unwrap()];
```

adding a lot of boilerplate. Also when I need to pass it to a function that accepts &[f32], it's a bit of a pain to convert.

What's the idiomatic way of handling a situation like this?

Edit: if it's changed 300. to 3., since in the example I'm talking about people heights in meters.

Comment: Since `try_from` could raise an error here, it is Not always safe to pass it as a `&[f32]`. Why not to use `from()`, and filter all invalid values before calling it?

Comment: I think try_from better suits this case, because I want to guarantee by design that this type cannot exist out of the very specific subset of f32. So if any user (including me in the future) tries to creates it with an invalid value, it should return Err.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a macro to call `Height::try_from(x).unwrap()`?

Something like `h!(3.0)`

As for the function that wants &[f32], to safely convert from [Height] -> [f32] you would have to construct a new slice using the f32's from the Heights which is O(n) so not too fast.

A better question is **why** does the function want &[f32] and can you change it?

Comment: Yes a macro is also what I was thinking about.
In my specific use case, I'm dealing with signals. The signals I'm dealing with are normalized, so their value is between 0. and 100., but the function accepting &[f32] is a filter, which in general could accept any f32 values. So I can change it, but it would be better to keep it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward and idiomatic way is using iterators and `map`:

```
let raw_heights = vec![6.7, 5.8, 0.1, 4.4];

let heights: Vec<Height> = raw_heights.into_iter()
    .map(|rh| Height::try_from(rh).unwrap())
    .collect();
```

See a full working example in the Rust Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=61a42b0a86c64f4a75bf4094da88b301

You could also use `macro_rules` for that, but it's an overkill.